# When I click "Open in new tab" on my S3 images, it downloads the image instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow All",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny All Actions On All But Media and Static Unless Defined User",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::**********:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/media/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/static/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So basically I have 3 folders: `backup`, `static` and `media`. All the objects in my media and static folders are public.

However when I click on the full path, for example this object: `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/media/x12wHSRoM9szjvY` (this obj doesn't actually exist but the path is the same format) there is no .jpg or .png extension even though it is an image. Could this be the reason for my problem and if so, how can I fix this so I can access the raw object and not download it when I click on it?

Comment: Your bucket policy is just reverse. You have made `put`,`get` public and overwritten media/static private. You need to reverse the settings.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want though - default private but media and static overwritten to be public. That part is working fine.

Comment: Why do you have the `Deny` policy? Buckets are private by default until something grants access via `Allow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object stored in Amazon S3 can also have [Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html). This metadata identifies the **type of file** that is stored, eg `image/jpeg`.

When the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) uploads a file, it typically sets the Metadata values, so it should work fine.

However, if your method of uploading does not set the Metadata values, then the browser has no way of knowing the type of file. It will then offer to download the file rather than displaying it. (The filename extensions such as .png and .jpg don't actually set the file type.)

See: [How Do I Add Metadata to an S3 Object? - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html)